# (Optical microscopy) Resolution improvement by using oil immersion

Tags: microscopy

'Oil-immersion' technique is widely used to increase the numerical aperture, and hence the resolution in optical microscopy.
Some microscope manufactures like Nikon or ZEISS explain the principle of oil-immersion technique like this.

[image: https://www.microscopyu.com/tutorials/immersion]

[image: https://zeiss-campus.magnet.fsu.edu/articles/basics/resolution.html]

They explain that the numerical aperture is increased because the light doesn't experience the difference of the refractive index when we use oil between the cover glass and the objective lens.
Therefore, we can collect more light than putting them in the air.

But I don't agree the pictures above.
I think the **maximum angle of the cone** which can collect the light is similar in both cases, air and oil.
**However in oil, the wavelength is reduced by the refractive index.**
Therefore, the **radius of the Airy disk is reduced** in oil.
I express my opinion as a picture.

[image]

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Numerical aperture is all about capturing the largest cone of rays from the specimen and passing those rays through the optical system of the microscope.
In telescope terms think of it as increasing the diameter of the objective lens to get better resolution.

The [simulation from Nikon](https://www.microscopyu.com/tutorials/immersion) shows this.

[image]

The refractive index of the oil is shown in a red rectangle with the corresponding value of the numerical aperture in a yellow rectangle.